# Oracle CLOB insert and search from .NET Client

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, blob, text-search

I am trying to create document management system on .NET.
The system requires pdf, docx, etc files to be stored and searched in content.

I want to store them on Oracle DB so that I can utilize Oracle text search features in document. However I could not find a proper way of inserting the document into database from .NET client so that I can make text search later.
Simply inserting byte array to CLOB column does not give power of text search features for pdf, docx files.

dbms_lob.loadfromfile Oracle query requires the file to be present on database server. However my file in on application server. So this is not an option.

How can I do it?

Comment: PDF and Docx files are binary, Oracle full text search will not be able to help you. You could analyse the file in .NET, build an index and store the index in the database.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thank you.

Comment: @Chet, Oracle supports search on these types. From official document: "Oracle Text can filter and extract content from different document formats. It
supports a large number of document formats including popular ones like the
Microsoft Office file formats, the Adobe PDF family of formats, HTML and
XML. 
" http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/11goracletexttwp-133192.pdf

Comment: @AhmetAltun birşey değil

Comment: Learn something new every day, thanks.

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/CCAPP/toc.htm) looks like a good place to start. Have you seen it yet?

Comment: Ah, wait. You said (or implied) you're inserting binary data into a CLOB. Shouldn't you be inserting into a BLOB?